# How to use guard statement to detect nil after an assignment?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use guard statement to check against nil.

I'm puzzled why the following let it slip through and generate a BAD_EXEC error:

```
    guard let event:Event! = eventsImagesLoading.removeValueForKey(location) else {
        return
    }
    images[location] = responseData
    event!.iconImgData = images[location]
```

I'm trying to check if "event" is nil after the method call. If it is it should just return. But in reality it slips through and crashes on the event!.iconImageData... line.

Comment: It's not slipping through -- the BAD_EXEC happens when it reaches `let event:Event!`, as you are trying to force the `nil` event (which `guard` will handle) into a non-optional type.

Comment: @James: actually, it _is_ slipping through, since assignment ("binding") of an optional to a same-type optional will always succeed. Implicitly unwrapped optionals may _hold_ value `nil` (without runtime exception), but should never be used when of value `nil`,  as this is to be equivalent to them being uninitialized (as we, as developers, should only use them when we know them not to hold value `nil`). Hence, the `guard let ... else` block above will always slip through, as the assignment ("binding") will always succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers show you how to solve your issue, but doesn't really explain why this error occurs, so I thought I'd pitch in on that.

---

The `guard let ... else` statement, much like `if let ...`, attempts to bind the unwrapped value of an optional---generally as long as this is not `nil`---to a non-optional immutable of the same underlying type; using optional binding

```
var a: Int? = 5
if let b = a {
    // b unwrapped, type inferred to non-optional type Int
    print(b) // "5"
}
```

The above binding would fail if `a` had the value `nil`, as `b`, as per default (by type inference), is of type `Int` which cannot hold `nil`.

In this context, it makes no sense to explicitly declare `b` to be an implicitly unwrapped optional, as this will allow a successful binding even if `a` is nil. An equivalently non-sense block would be to explicitly declare `b` to be an optional, whereafter the "attempted optional binding" of optional `a` (`Int?`) to optional `b` (`Int?`) would naturally always succeed, and the `if let ...` block reduces to a completely redundant block-local assignment.

```
a = nil

if let b: Int! = a {
    print(b) // "nil"
    // wups, we managed to bind a to b even though a is nil ...

    // note also this peculiarity
    print(b.dynamicType) // Optional<Int>
    let c: Int! = nil
    print(c.dynamicType) // ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
}

if let b: Int? = a {
    print(b) // nil
    // wups, we managed to bind a to b even though a is nil ...
}
```

Note the peculiarity that no matter if we explicitly specify `b` to be of type `Int?` (optional) or type `Int!` (implicitly unwrapped optional), the binded immutable `b` passing into the `if let` block is, for both cases, just a regular optional (of type `Int?`). This explains why you need to unwrap `event` (`event!.iconImgData`) *after* the `guard let` clause, even though we declared it to be of an implicitly unwrapped type.

Hence, in your example, your `guard let ... else` statement will not catch cases where `eventsImagesLoading.removeValueForKey(location)` is `nil`, as the binding to `event` (which is of implicitly unwrapped optional type `Event!`) will success even for `nil` cases.

```
func foo() {
    let bar : Int? = nil
    guard let _: Int! = bar else {
        print("this is surely nil")
        return

    }
    print("but an implicitly unwrapped optional will fall through")
}
foo() // "but an implicitly unwrapped optional will fall through"
```

You should generally only use implicitly unwrapped optionals for immutables where you need delayed initialization (value `nil` until initialized). After initialization of an implicitly unwrapped optional, its value should never be `nil` (whereas in the example above, it's value is, after initialization by optional binding, just that; `nil`).

Also, you should generally let the compiler infer the *non-optional* type of the immutable to which you are trying to bind in the `guard let INFER_THIS = ... else` or `if let INFER_THIS = ...` clauses.

---

We could ponder over whether it should even be allowed to use optional binding *to* optional types (guaranteed success), but that is another discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Event!` to `Event` (line 1) and `event!` to `event` (line 5).

Answer (score 1):

```
guard let event:Event = eventsImagesLoading.removeValueForKey(location) else {
        return
    }
    images[location] = responseData
    event.iconImgData = images[location]
```