# Optional binding to an immutable explicitly declared to be of type 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>' yields an immutable of type 'Optional<T>'

Tags: swift

### Background

When I was explaining the logical error in the following question:

- [How to use guard statement to detect nil after an assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36303241/4573247)

I stumbled over a peculiarity that I cannot explain myself.

---

### Details and question

As shown in the thread above, we can explicitly state the type of the scope-local immutable, say `b`, in `if let b = rhs ...` and `guard let b = rhs ... else` clauses to be of the same optional type as the `rhs` value to (attempted to be assigned) to `b`, in which case the "optional binding" will always succeed:

```
let a: Int?

// ...

if let b: Int? = a { // will always succeed, 'Int?' to 'Int?'
    print(b.dynamicType) // Optional<Int>
}
```

We could discuss whether this should even be allowed, as this is in essence a bloated block-local assignment, but this is not the point of this question. Rather, explaining the following peculiarity:

- If we explicitly declare `b` above to be of an implicitly unwrapped optional type (here: `Int!`), then `b` in the scope of the `if let` clause is, for some reason, just a regular non-unwrapped optional, namely `Int`.

  ```
  let a: Int? = nil
  if let b: Int! = a {
      print(b.dynamicType) // Optional<Int>
          /* why not ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int> ? */
  }
  ```

**Question:**

- Why is `b` above—declared to be an implicitly unwrapped optional (`Int!`)—converted to a "regular" optional (`Int?`) (in the `if let` clause)?

---

### Investigations of my own

I've simply noted that the above "shadow conversion" is naturally not present for regular assignments of optionals to implicitly unwrapped optionals

```
let c: Int? = 10
let d: Int! = c
print(f.dynamicType) // ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
```

neither present if we use an always-succeeding `if let` block-local assignment from non-optional (`Int`) to implicitly unwrapped optional (`Int!`)

```
let c = 10
if let d: Int! = c {
    print(d.dynamicType) // ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
}
```

After feedback from @Sulthan in the comments below, we see that this "shadow conversion" is not present if `a` above is a double optional (`Int??`), e.g.

```
let a: Int?? = 10
if let b: Int! = a {
    print(b.dynamicType) // ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>
}
if let b: Int? = a {
    print(b.dynamicType) // Optional<Int>
}
```

---

I am using Swift 2.2 / Xcode 7.3.

Comment: The reason for `if let b: Int? = a` to exist is unwrapping of double optionals. `a` in this case gets promoted to `Int??` and one level of optional is correctly removed. I cannot answer your question about `!` but it's possible the right side of the expression gets promoted to something unexpected.

Comment: @Sulthan I see, that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Sulthan Interestingly, the above (question issue) is not present if `a` is such a double optional (`Int??`), then `if let b: Int? ...` and `if let b: Int! ...` end up with those specified types.

Comment: I know, I have just went through a series of tests myself. I think you have find a bug. It's a corner case when the `if let` expression does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Also, I cannot really find the rules how `Optional<X>` and `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<X>` can be converted to each other. There seems to be some implicit cast.

Comment: Info: filed a bug report for this [here (SR-1123)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1123).