# About variable type in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I understand the difference between `String!` type and `String?` type. But what about `String` type? How does it differs from `String!` and `String?` in swift? Does `String!` type identical to `String` type?

Say, I have a class like this:

```
class Person {
  private var _name: String!

  var name: String {
      return _name
  }

  init(name: String) {
     _name = name
  }
}
```

There is no compiler error, looks like `String` type is identical to `String!` type. But I am not sure...

Answer (score 4):

`String` and `String!` are not identical. There is just happens to be enough sugar in the language to convert between them. Similarly there is sugar in the language to convert between `String` and `String?` (but not in reverse).

Start with the basics. There is `String`. Unless there is some strong reason, you should use `String` when you mean a string of characters. Everything else is "more stuff" and you shouldn't add it unless you need it.

There is `Optional<String>`. This is just an enum with two cases, one with a value, and one without a value:

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
    // ...
}
```

There is a postfix operator `!` for `Optional` which will return `Wrapped` if it's available, and crash if it is not. So far, no magic. This is stuff you could build yourself.

There are are few pieces of magic around `Optional`. First, the type `Wrapped?` is magically converted to `Optional<Wrapped>` by the compiler (for any `Wrapped`). This is just syntactic sugar. The two notations are identical. Second, there is optional-chaining with the `?.` "operator" (it's not really an operator; it's part of the language and you couldn't build it yourself). And then there's optional promotion. Any type `Wrapped` can be automatically and implicitly converted to `Wrapped?` if needed. There are are few other pieces of magic around `Optional` like `if-let` syntax, and there's `nil` which is a synonym for `Optional.None` (I believe they're actually identical). But `Optional` really is just a generic type, implemented as an enum. It's just a type the compiler knows special things about.

Then there is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Wrapped>`. This is also just an enum (in Swift 2.2; this will change in Swift 3).

```
public enum ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
    // ...
}
```

This is not the same as `Optional` and it is not the same as `Wrapped`. It's a completely different type. But it also has some magic associated with it. First, the type `Wrapped!` is syntactic sugar for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Wrapped>`. Again, it's just sugar. The two are the same (in Swift 2.2, not in Swift 3). Next, if `IUO<Wrapped>` is found in a place that `Wrapped` is expected, it will automatically be converted to `Wrapped` or crash if there is no value. If it is found in a place that `Wrapped?` is expected, it will automatically be converted to `Wrapped?`. Those are magical, and it's why sometimes `String` and `String!` *seem* to be the same type. That's just the compiler magically "making it work" for you by adding an invisible conversion step. It doesn't mean they're really the same type.

IUO is mostly useful in bridging to certain Objective-C patterns, especially involving Storyboards, and should be avoided outside of those situations. Even in those situations, IUO is just there for convenience. You could do all the same things using regular Optionals, you'd just have to check them with `if-let` more often. Using Optionals is much safer than using IUO. It's easy to think "I know for certain this value will always be set before it is used." And just this week I chased down a crasher due to being wrong about that. There's a difference between "it should be" and "it must be." But, being totally safe with Optionals in Storyboards could be very inconvenient and might mask some bugs (by doing nothing rather than crashing), so that's the most common place for IUO.

IUO properties used to be valuable for dealing with failable `init` methods. That's no longer a problem in Swift 2.2, so that use has gone away. The last "pure Swift" use that I run into is when you must pass `self` to the initializer of something you store as a property (you can't pass `self` at that point because all your properties have been initialized). That's an unfortunate use-case and very messy, and I hope we come up with a fix for it. Outside of these kinds of cases, you should avoid Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals.

Answer (score 1):

`String` and `String!` are same and different at the same time. If you declare let or var as `String`, you will have to set some value at `init` method. If you declare it as `String!` you can set value when you want but you must do it before reading this value.

So, if your `_name` will be `nil`, your app will crash.

If you declare it as `String`, compiler guarantees that `_name != nil` before the first reading. If you declare it as `String!`, you should guarantee it.

This things have same type because of this:

```
var test1: String = "test"
var test2: String! = "test"

if test1 is String { // True
    print("test1 is String")
}
if test2 is String { // True
    print("test2 is String")
}
```

This types are equal but this things are different

Comment: `String` and `String!` are not equal, per se, and they have some subtle differences. The latter is an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` wrapping a `String`, and even if it is "implicitly unwrapped", you may use e.g. a `String!` instance in a conditional binding block (`if let foo = bar { }` for `bar` being of type `String!`), whereas you may not for "pure" `String` instance. They do, however, _in practice_ have many similarities, however e.g. safety not being one of them.

Comment: @Artyom, Based on your explaination, is it so that it is better to declare `_name` with type `String` instead of `String!`, so that compiler will always remind me to set a value in `init` & my app will have less chance to crash, otherwise if like what I do now, `_name` is of type `String!`, I could get a nil value & crash my app accidentally?

Comment: @Leem.fin You can't initialize your example class without name, but you can set nil to name after that and it can cause crash if your variable will be accessed

Comment: It is better to declare variables as `String` but you can't do that everywhere. For example, your `@IBOutlet` always will be `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` (`UIView!` for example) because they values can't be set at initialization

Comment: @dfri I've updated my answer (about equality of this things)

Comment: The fact that `is String` passes does not mean that `String!` and `String` are the same type. It just means that the compiler is willing to implicitly convert between them. Compare `test1.dynamicType` and `test2.dynamicType` to see the difference. It's also worth noting that while you *can* use IUOs for `@IBOutlet`, you don't have to. You can also use regular Optionals. IUOs are a convenience (and not always a major one), not a requirement there.

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference between these two functions:

```
func f() {
    let x: String? = nil
    guard let y: String = x else {
        print("failed")
        return
    }
}

func g() {
    let x: String? = nil
    guard let y: String! = x else {
        print("failed")
        return
    }
    print(y.dynamicType, y)
}

f() # failed
g() # Optional<String> nil
```

Comment: This is a very interesting corner case, but may confuse more than it enlightens (it might even be a compiler bug, though if it is, it'll be irrelevant in Swift 3). The output is suggesting that `String!` and `String?` are the same type, but that's not what's happening. I'm certain that the `guard-let` is promoting `x` to `String??` which is why it succeeds. The promoted `String??` has a value; that value is `.Some(nil)` (which is completely different than `nil`). Compare your example to this simpler one: `let x: String? = nil; let z: String! = x; print(z.dynamicType)`.

Comment: @RobNapier I do believe this is a compiler bug limited to explicitly declaring the type binded to as `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` in `if let` and `guard let` clauses`, as I previously pondered over [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304448/optional-binding-to-an-immutable-explicitly-declared-to-be-of-type-implicitlyun). Bug report has been filed [here (SR-1123)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1123), but as you say, it'll should irrelevant (and already implicitly fixed :) in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are better to read [swift documentation](https://swift.org/documentation/TheSwiftProgrammingLanguage(Swift2.2).epub) than any answer here. Properly undestandig swift's type system is very important, so do it first.

Answer (score -1):

both `String!` and `String?` are optional types.

Using `String?` requires you to test whether the value is *nil* (.None) or a value (.Some). For example using guard statements or if-let clauses.

`String!` is an optional that is assumed to be non-nil and is unwrapped automatically. This allows you to write cleaner-looking code and avoid unwrapping wherever the value is used. BUT: if your value is *nil* a fatal error will occur.

Comment: This will be true in Swift 3, but is not true in 2.2. `String!` is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>` which is a different type than `Optional<String>`.

Comment: is _ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional_ a subtype of _Optional_?

Comment: No. You can't have a subtype of an enum.

Comment: I changed my answer.